# dual boot install windows7 after ubuntu12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

cannot install windows7 (dual boot) after installing ubuntu12.04.
I want to install windows7 currently i have ubuntu12.04.
I want to dual boot unetbootin does not work.
I have ubnutu12.04 currently installed please tell me the steps to install windows along side
[image]

this is what happens and it does not boot automatically even after timeout

Comment: please add some more information.

Comment: Can't you install it alongside - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support - what happens when you reach Step 4? Anyway, you need to **install Windows First**, leave space on the disk, and then install Ubuntu alongside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## depending on your technical proficiency, please do take heed of the

BACKUP YOURFILES  WARNING!

1. Install gparted.
2. Partition your drive/s to take windows (read up on gparted if you are technophobic)
3. backup your grub partition (read up on this before loading the new windows partition)
4. reboot with the windows set up disk and install
5. boot with our backed up OD on the USB key (with your backed up grub!)
6. boot into the repair section
7. do "grub update"
8. do the fsk
9. do the update
10. drop into root shell
11. start gdm (of  whichever window manager you are using - if its 12.04 this is probably fine if it fails  try the others  LightDm /kde etc)
12. log in and  do the grub update thingy using term again to be sure.
13. reboot.

Some times this doesnt work so make sure you read up on how to probe for the OS using the OS prober..

### Good  luck and remember

## TO BACK EVERYTHING UP FIRST

Answer (score 1):

Using the `winusb` software in ubuntu,you can make a bootable windows usb.Run the below commands in terminal to install `winusb`,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

After creating the `windows live usb`,boot from it and install `windows 7`alongside with ubuntu by selecting the appropriate `ntfs` partition.

To install windows alongside with ubuntu,please refer [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) or [`this`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).